# Android Studio C++/JNI project: how to add flag '-stdlib=libc++'?

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake, java-native-interface

I wonder how and where (probably in Gradle) I can add the flag '-stdlib=libc++' in my Android studio Java/C++/JNI/CMake project ? Indeed, it seems that Android Studio don't find all C/C++ standard libs at compilation and I suspect that such a flag is missing somewhere (I have got it in the iOS version of my project).

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#selecting_a_c_runtime

Comment: Thanks @rustyx Unfortunately, I am not sure to understand what I should do when I read this doc... Are you able to provide more details? Thanks.